# Adding labels in VrPanoramaView (Google VR in Android Studio)

Tags: virtual-reality, google-cardboard, android-sdk-2.3, google-vr

I want to mark/tag places within my 360 image view. I'm aware VrPanoramaView does not support touch events. Can we at least put labels to 360 images by specifying location coordinates within the VR view? If yes, could you give me an insight to the method?

Answer (score 0):

VrPanoramaView is meant to be a lightweight widget and doesn't support adding 3D labels. If you want additional functionality, you will need to create a 360 pano viewer using the base GVR SDK. Then you can use something like http://www.felixjones.co.uk/neo%20website/Android_View/ to render an Android TextView inside your VR scene.